# magento add to cart issues

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

when Iam trying to click 'Add to cart' button, it keeps loading, could anyone please tell me, what could be the issue?

**BELOW LINK:**

```
http://mobilesplaza.com/tablets.html
```

when Iam trying to click 'Add to cart' button, its showing me as 'Error'could anyone please tell me, what could be the issue?

**BELOW LINK:**

```
http://mobilesplaza.com/tablets/chromo-incr-7-android-4-1-capacitive-5-point-multi-touch-screen-white-new-model-september-2013.html
```

I refreshed Indexes, Cache too, BUT still not understanding. Does above issues really programmatic issue?

Answer (score 1):

JS Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: stLight is not defined` tablets.html:16

Answer (score 0):

Add this line 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursit.com/button/buttons.js"></script>

Before
<script type="text/javascript"> stLight.options({publisher: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>